# Is there a KFold splitter that avoids putting labels (unique, only occur once) into the test set that are unseen in the training set?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Essentially, my test set contains labels (features) that are not present in the training set sometimes.

This is because there are roughly ~100 labels overall, in a 500 observation dataset.

Being a student from a different field, I made a low-quality solution for it but I was wondering if there was a part of SKLearn or a similar package that deals with this.

This was my solution for the time being:

```
i, a = [1, 1]
while a is not None:  
    X_train, X_validation, y_train, y_validation = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.95)  
    b = y_validation.isin(y_train).value_counts() 
    print(str(f"While labels between sets are mismatched splitting will repeat. Current iteration: {i}"))
    i = i + 1  
    a = b.get(False)  
print(f"Splitting Completed Successfully\n")
```

So without this, if I ran some ML algorithms, they would fail for obvious reasons; "feature in test set is not found in training set", essentially.

I tried to search if there was an elegant solution to this but I don't think I came across anything (other than a solution in R via caret) for this.

I should add, the issue is some labels are only seen once in the entire dataset - so it's impossible to stratify them across both.

Comment: Perhaps [`StratifiedKFold` or `StratifiedShuffleSplit`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#stratification "Click me!") can help you.

Comment: @rickhg12hs that would work if my dataset had at least 2 instances of all labels but it doesn't - so I cannot stratify.